# Connecting network drives when there isn't a normal login

Tags: windows, network-shares, login

The basic problem is a background task being run as a service needs access to a network drive.  Unfortunately the device only permits one login per user and apparently there's a separate login attempted--the drive fails to map.  (And the program has no facility to run a command before the task starts as it's acting as a slave to another machine in this case--there's no start of task to trigger an external command.)

Ok, we created a separate user whose only purpose is to access this, gave the program that user's credentials and everything was fine--until the box was rebooted.  Log in as that user and the network drive is there but the service doesn't see it if that login isn't performed first.

How do I get my drive mapped??

Comment: have you tried running the service under an account that has access to the share?

Comment: @FrankThomas It has to be an account that isn't otherwise being used or the login gets refused.